# Winston - Logging with dynamic file name (separate log file for each .feature file)

Tags: javascript, logging, protractor, winston

I am using protractor cucumber framework for my test automation. For logging i am using 'Winston'. I have multiple feature files. I want to keep log files in the name of feature file for better tracking.

As of now i hard coded file name as shown below in 'filename' property [filename: 'c:\QAAutomation\info.log'].

Is there any option in Winston to assign dynamic file name ?

```js
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

winston.emitErrs = true;

var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
      level: 'info',
      name: 'info-file',
      filename: 'c:\\QAAutomation\\info.log',
      handleExceptions: true,
      json: false,
      prepend: true,
      datePattern: 'yyyyMMdd',
      maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
      maxFiles: 60,
      colorize: false,
      formatter: customFileFormatter,
      timestamp: function() {
        return moment().format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS");
      }
    })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});

module.exports = logger;
module.exports.stream = {
  write: function(message, encoding) {
    logger.verbose(message);
  }
};

function customFileFormatter(options) {
  // Return string will be passed to logger.
  return `{"timestamp": "${options.timestamp()}", "level": "${options.level}", "message": "${(options.message ? options.message : '')
        + (options.meta && Object.keys(options.meta).length ? '\n\t' + JSON.stringify(options.meta) : '')}"}`;
}
```